# How to directly put the scanned QR-code data into the textbox in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Hello guys I copied code on how to create a QR-code scanner in YouTube using JavaScript. The code is working fine as you see in the picture, but I want the data that's generated by the QR-code to go directly into the "Member ID" textbox.

**This is the aspx code I included the book ID, member name, book name.**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div style="width:400px;" id="reader"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <h4>SCAN RESULT</h4>
      <br/>
      <div id="result">Result Here</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label>Member ID</label>
    <div class="form-group">
      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" class="form-control" runat="server" placeholder="Member ID"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label>Book ID</label>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" class="form-control" runat="server" placeholder="Book ID"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button class="btn btn-primary" ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Go" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label>Member Name</label>
    <div class="form-group">
      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" class="form-control" runat="server" placeholder="Member Name" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label>Book Name</label>
    <div class="form-group">
      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" class="form-control" runat="server" placeholder="Book Name" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**This the javascript code.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function onScanSuccess(qrCodeMessage) {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '<span class="result">' + qrCodeMessage + '</span>';
  }

  function onScanError(errorMessage) {
    //handle scan error
  }
  var html5QrcodeScanner = new Html5QrcodeScanner(
    "reader", {
      fps: 10,
      qrbox: 250
    });
  html5QrcodeScanner.render(onScanSuccess, onScanError);
</script>
```

I tried to direct the element id to the id of member id and the code doesn't work anymore.

Please help me guys.

[image]

Comment: Any errors occurred?

Comment: there were no errors I just want the scanned result(data) to go directly to the member ID textbox